# What's the name for a function which translates faithfully into a quotient, i.e. commutes with the quotient?

Tags: functions, commutative-algebra, terminology, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

What's the name for a function which translates faithfully into a quotient, i.e. commutes with the quotient?

I'll use the example of a group.  Let $X$ be a group and $X/Y$ be its quotient.

Let $f:X\to X$ have the property that $\forall x\in X: \forall \{xy:y\in Y\} :f(xy)=f(x)y$

As an example, in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ the function $f(x)=x+n$ has this property.

I always say that $f$ commutes with the quotient.  Is there a more widely used terminology for this?  And is there a terminology e.g. outside of groups - in *any* quotient, e.g. in a monoid or a topological quotient space?

This always implies that $f:X/Y\to X/Y$ is well-defined as a function.

Comment: I have seen phrases like '$f$ _respects the the fibers of_ $q$' (where $q : X \to X/\sim$ is the quotient map). Also, if the quotient is given by an action of some group $G$, then, we say that "$f$ is $G$-equivariant map". See [equivariant maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_map).

Comment: Thanks @feynhat - more than I hoped for! 